# PHP ini directive per directory depending of request_uri

Tags: php, apache, symfony1, apache2

I'm trying to change the size limit of an upload. I know I have to change those directive, in Apache configuration (some can't be changed using ini_set)

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 3600
php_value max_input_time         3600
php_value max_execution_time     3600
php_value upload_max_filesize    10M
php_value post_max_size          110M
```

Unfortunately, I can't do that directly in a `<Directory>` of my virtualhost, since the directory is always the same (I'm using a front controller, thus all request go through index.php & are dispatched to the proper controller - I use Symfony)

My question, then, is how can I avoid this problem ? I don't want to set those values for the whole application, only for a specific action.

Comment: I've just updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, depending on how you map to your front controller. If you're doing it via rewrite rules then you can use a `<Location>` instead of `<Directory>` block to specify a chunk of path you want to change the settings for. `<LocationMatch>` lets you use a regexp for the same thing.

If all of your external URLs really start with `/index.php?` then consider setting up a redirect rule especially for these requests:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo/$ ^/index.php [L]

<Location /foo/>
    php_value ...
</Location>
```

If that's not the case, you'll need to tell us more about your application structure.

Comment: Did you manage to set a php_value inside the `Location` or `LocationMatch` directive? I am using Apache 2.4 and it won't let me do it. It doesn't do anything. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround would be to create a directory with a single PHP file inside that implements your action and have the script that submits the POST target that file using a "custom" URL. After processing the input you would redirect back to a normal page through `index.php`. It's not clean, but it should work.

It could also be worth considering what exactly you stand to gain from this.

- it does not make any sense to set `session.gc_maxlifetime` in just *one* action (especially if you are increasing it)
- limiting `max_input_time` to one hour also does not make sense if `max_execution_time` is also one hour
- `max_execution_time` can be set at runtime
- the other two directives cannot be set at runtime, but the POST size should not matter and the uploaded file size *can* be checked at runtime and handled accordingly

So, what's the aim here?